# How to play sound from base64 converted files using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, audio, base64

Would like to play a mp3 converted file in base64 using bash script.

First I have done this:
`base64 notification.mp3 > notification.b64`

then I tried to play notification.b4, but none of them worked:

```
play notification.b64
cat notification.b64 /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
play < $(cat notification.b64 | base64 --decode)
```

I'm using Debian Buster, so there is no /dev/audio or /dev/dsp.

I'm trying to put this inside a script, to avoid additional files and be able to play the base64 inside a variable.

Comment: what package is `play` from? `dpkg -S $(realpath $(which play))`

Comment: does `play notification.mp3` work?

Comment: yes, play is from sox. But it is not what I want. `play notification.mp3` is ok, I need to play base64 converted audio file.

Comment: `... | play -t mp3 -` or `play -t mp3 <( ... )`

Comment: @jhnc thank you! `base64 -d notification.b64 | play -t mp3 -` works perfect! Please answer the question, not comment, so I can upvote and select your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The play command (from sox) uses the filename extension to decide what type of file it is processing.

- It doesn't know how to handle the `.b64` extension
- If you feed it input from a pipe or process substition, it doesn't have a filename

The solution is to explicitly tell it what kind of input it should expect. The `-t` option is provided for this. So, in your case you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -d @ sound <<'EOD'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EOD

echo "$sound" | base64 --decode | play -t mp3 -
```

`sox -h` should display all the formats that your version understands. (On ubuntu, for example, handling mp3 requires an additional library to be installed). See also soxformat(7) for more details.